# TFS 2010 Release Candidate Can't Create SharePoint Site Error

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2010

I have installed a deployment of Team Foundation Server 2010 Release Candidate and I am connecting through Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Release Candidate. When I try to create a new Team Project I get an error **"TF250044 SharePoint Site can not be created in the following location: Server Name Here"** It also tells me that my user account does not have permissions to create sites in SharePoint but my user account has full rights in SharePoint.

I have checked everywhere and as far as I know I have full permissions in SharePoint, if someone encountered this problem and solved it please help.

Thank You!

Comment: Is the SharePoint collection for TFS configured according to the TFS Administration Console, and can it connect successfully?

Comment: Yes from TFS point of view everything is just fine. But from the Client I can't add a Team Project. Real Frustrating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default when you try to create a new Team Project, Visual Studio sets a default path for the SharePoint site.

```
[SharePoint Server]/sites/[TFS Project Collection Name]/[Team Project Name]
```

What you want to do is create the site collection for the [TFS Project Collection Name] or remove it and create the Team Project Site in the sites root.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like someone else said, you might want to remove the associated SharePoint association from the TFS Admin Console and create it again.  Did you upgrade this server?  I had a problem with a recent upgrade from TFS 2008 where I had a Team Project with the same name as the new TFS Project Collection.  That created all sorts of conflicts.